# How to fix this numbering in section?

Tags: sectioning

Is there any way in which I can either hide the 5.1 and 5.1.1? So I can directly use what I set to the right

I would need to do this hiding only for specific subsections /subsubsections

[image]

Comment: Try `\section*{<Your section title>}` instead of `\section{<Your section Title>}` After that look for the usage `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{<Your toc -table of contents- content>}` if you need to add the specific sections in the table of contents

Comment: you should provide the sample text as text not an image, but you can use `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}` so you get ` not 5.1 and use `\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.(\Alph{subsection})}` so you get 1.(A)

Comment: Perfect, that \section* was exactly what I was needing. Thanks guys